# MVC project and webforms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have an MVC project and I want to add a webform to it and integrate it with the MVC theme. The web form always runs in a new page not showing the menu.

Comment: Check this, it might help https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-webform-view-with-a-razor-layout-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: What have you tried? What is your specific question?